# How to generate increasing periodic sequences without using "if condition/loop/states"?

Tags: python, numpy, math, sequence

---

For example, period=4:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]
y = [1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2  3  4  1  2 ]
```

For this, I can simply do y=((x-1) % 4) + 1

I'm looking to generate a sequence with increasing periods.

Example 1: initial period = 2, doubles every time it passes through a period(p).

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]
p = [2 2 4 4 4 4 8 8 8  8  8  8  8  8]
y = [1 2 1 2 3 4 1 2 3  4  5  6  7  8]
```

Example 2: initial period = 3, doubles every time it passes through a period(p).

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21]
p = [3 3 3 6 6 6 6 6 6 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12]
y = [1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
```

Is there anyway to generate y values without using any for loop/if condition/states, get y values when only given x?

If given sequence x and we know the initial period, is there any way to compute sequence y without using any for loops/if conditions/states saving?

Comment: please add comas after each item in list.

Comment: For the first example: no, you cannot. `4 % 4` is `0`.

Comment: Your question is extremely inadequate. What is given? What do you expect? Is the period always going to be a power of 2?

Comment: What's with the weird "no if conditions" constraint?

Comment: @timgeb Don't forget the `without using any for loop/if condition/states` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to find modulo (p) and sequence value (y) for given number x, but it requires using floating-arithmetics logarithm.

```
pow = Floor(Log2(x+1))
p = 1 << pow
y = 1 + (x + 1) % p
```

For initial period s (3 in your second example)

```
pow = Floor(Log2((x + s - 1) / s))
p = s * (1 << pow)
y = 1 + (x + s - 1) % p

check:
x=9 pow = 1 p = 6 y = 6
x=10 pow = 2 p = 12 y = 1
x=21 pow = 2 p = 12 y = 12
```

Comment: The question is: *without `if` condition checks* ...

Comment: Thanks. This is really close to what I'm looking for. However, if the base is equal 3, I think taking log with base 3 is not my desired outcome as I only wanted to double the period.  I've updated my question with a new example. I apologized for asking the question poorly.

Comment: I update my answer for any initial period and doubling. But you also added zeros in example 1...

Comment: Wow, great thanks. In fact, the first thing I tried was similar, but it was "pow = Floor(Log2(x + 1 / s))". I missed the bracket and I thought my intuition was completely wrong. I've also updated example 1 to be consistent. Last question, if possible, the reason for using (x+s-1) instead of (x) is to drop the values in the function that are less than s?

Comment: Your mapping omits 0-th period, so some range shifting does exist, and +s-1 compensates it. (new series start from 3,7,15 rather than powers of two)

Comment: I also found out if I change the "log base/pow" to 3 from 2, meaning I want to triple the period every passtrhough, the algorithm above won't work. Did I do something wrong or is it intended to work only for doubling?

Comment: Geometric progression sum is `S=(q^n-1)/(q-1)` so to get n for arbitrary q one need `n=log[q] (S*(q-1)+1)` or for q=3: `n=log3 (2*S+1)`

Answer (score 0):

For scalar `x` we can give a pure Python method using `bit_length`:

```
>>> def periods_py(x):
...    return (x+2)^(1<<(x+2).bit_length()-1)
... 
>>> [periods_py(i) for i in range(1, 15)]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0]
```

For vector `x` the closest `numpy` replacement for `bit_length` I could find is `frexp`:

```
>>> def periods_np(x):
...    return (x+2)^(1<<np.frexp(x+2)[1]-1)
... 
>>> periods_np(np.arange(1, 15))
array([1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0])
```